# why an interstitial defect increases density in covalent solids and do not increases in ionic solid?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

The interstitial point defect increases the density of a solid. Frenkel defect is also a type of this defect but it do not increases the density.

Also, the mass / volume concept of density tells us that density should be same in both cases, as they are basically interstitial defect. Then what happened to a covalent solid that density increased , and why it didn't happened to ionic solid?

(Please understand that it is not a duplicate of
[Why Frenkel defect does not impact the density of the solid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/125400/121235) )

Comment: In the standard Fresnel case, the small ion is displaced. It fits easily in a position between the larger ions without disturbing them much, if at all. For other materials and structures that may not be the case.

Comment: Does that means that in an interstitial defect in covalent solids , the particle in void disturbed other particles due to greater size? Is this is the only reason for differeneces of observed density? thank you